# Java BigDecimal vs R vs Java Float, Double

Tags: java, r, bigdecimal

I am working on a financial system where precision required is 6 decimal places only.  We are currently using R but converting to Java.  I had a debate with a colleague over whether we should go with BigDecimals or double / float primitive in Java.  I was in favor of BigDecimal but his point was that R would be using primitives same as Java primitives so we would have already noticed if there were any issues with the precision.  It should be noted that the end result we would convert to BigDecimal anyway this is just for the calculation itself.  Who is correct here?

Comment: Thanks Basil good point will update now

Comment: I since did some research turns out R primitives behave differently to Java primitives .  One of the major issues in Java does not exist in R prim

Comment: In Java ---- double myStart = 0.2;
for (int i = 0; i < 109; i++) {
    myStart += 0.2;
}

you get the below answer
prim Sum =21.999999999999954

Comment: In R ----- > a = 0.2
> for (x in 1:109) {
+ a = a + 0.2
+ }
> print(a)
[1] answer is 22

Comment: Your code examples do **not** imply that R's floating point types behave differently from Java's. Your result is likely solely due the default formatting used by your print functions. R does not commit to a representation, but the docs do say that "...on all current platforms IEC 60559 (aka IEEE 754) arithmetic is used...", same as Java.

Comment: I am voting to reopen not because I think the close reason is incorrect but because I think in this particular case it does not serve the goal #1 of stackoverflow, namely to form an archive of useful programming questions with excellent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use BigDecimal with DECIMAL 128. You should do this knowing that specifications may change in the future and more decimal points may be required. DECIMAL 128 is too too much solution, but it's bullet proof.

Performance is important, but when it comes to money, accuracy is much much more important.

Comment: Thanks good point about specification change.

Answer (score 1):

## Accuracy

**Accountants want accuracy.** They don’t care about speed of execution. For accounting purposes, always use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in Java.

An alternative is using integers. If you want to represent pennies on the dollar (USD), multiply by a hundred, and then do further math with that integer. [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) may be helpful.

## Speed

**Statisticians want speed of execution.** They don’t care about [minor inaccuracies.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) For such work, floating-point in [R](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) makes sense.

You can export from `BigDecimal` [to double](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) or [to float](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#floatValue()).

Comment: Thanks my reputation isn't letting me vote the feedback up.